# Background color on div container does not scroll with page

Tags: html, css

Iv'e tried about 10 different solutions I've found on this site and others and still can't figure it out. Hoping for some help, (new to coding) thanks.

As stated, background color of my div container (my "sidebar") doesnt scroll with the page even though I have height to 100% on the container and its parent (the body tag). I suspect the body tag is the issue since its taking it as 100% of the browser window, and not the entire page. but if I take it out, the div background shrinks down to content. ".personal" is my sidebar and ".wrapper" is my main content on the page.

What my style tag/CSS looks like:

```
<div class="style">
    <style>

body {
        margin: 0 auto; 
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
    }

.wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

.personal {
        float:left;
        background-color: rgba(29, 32, 44, 0.85);
        color: snow;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    </style>
</div>
```

What my HTML looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style> </style>
  </head>
    <body>
         <div class="personal"> content </div>
         <div class="wrapper"> content </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: I'm not so sure now if my answer is what you're looking for...

Comment: @Gezzasa not quite. your solution worked but don't like how it affects the content as it all resizes when you resize the browser. thanks though

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you replace the percentage widths with your static widths again :). I used percentage because of the narrow vieport of jsfiddle.

Comment: ah, well it only resized with the window even with my px measurements. still no scrolling

Comment: Not sure what you want to scroll. They're both 100% to the viewport. If you want the one to be equal to the other according to content, then you can either use JS or display table views. That's my best guess. I'd like to see a pure CSS solution if anyone has one.

Comment: so I kind of solved it. made the sidebar fixed but then that causes the other div container to collapse behind it. so I made another div that floats to left of content with just a white background and a <br> tag and the same width as sidebar. so its kind of acting like an invisible container keeping the other container to the side of my sidebar.

Comment: `position: fixed;` to put it plain removes the space it takes up on the screen. That is why the container goes behind it. But you can fix this easy by putting a `padding-left` on the container with a width of the sidebar. I thought you wanted them the same height. Fixed won't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your  tags wrapped in a div tag?
Insert the style in the  of your html without the DIV and it will work fine.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }

    .personal {
      float: left;
      background-color: rgba(29, 32, 44, 0.85);
      color: snow;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="personal"> content </div>
  <div class="wrapper"> content </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure why, but I took it out and my code reflects yours and the issue still remains

Comment: here's a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/91brepj70hmxzkp/Screenshot%202018-02-06%2022.25.24.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a few lines to be able to get this work.

https://jsfiddle.net/8e95zqmt/

A couple of issues. Padding and Margin will add on to your width is you don't have `box-sizing: border-box;` style on your elements. Margin will still always add on width though. So if your wrapper is `600px` then with a `margin-left: 20px` it's actually `620px`. I changed your widths to percentage but you can change it back to px if you have a larger viewport. jsfiddle is small.

Percentage heights also means it's calculate according to the viewport and not content. There might be a css solution that I'm not aware of but the only way I know at present is using javascript.

**Here is the example but with your original static widths**

https://jsfiddle.net/vj4tu2zj/

Answer (score 0):

```
.personal {
        background-color: rgba(29, 32, 44, 0.85);
        color: snow; 
        Position:fixed;
        left:0;
        width: 300px;
        height: -webkit-fill-available;
    }
```

Make position is fixed

Comment: wasn't what I had In mind, but I would be fine with it being fixed and traveling with the scroll... but now it makes the other container collapse behind the side bar. they no longer float. how do i make the .wrapper float to the right of the .personal side after changing it to fixed

Comment: Ok, Remove fixed position and try with this " height: -webkit-fill-available;"

Comment: still no luck with that either

Answer (score -1):

very simple. just change "height" to "auto".

```
.personal {
        float:left;
        background-color: rgba(29, 32, 44, 0.85);
        color: snow;
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: didn't work, just shrunk the background color to the bottom of the content on the side bar